# Upstream Azure SignalR function issues Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Options runtime exception

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-signalr

**Note:** This issue is not duplicate despite the title reads similarly.

The following upstream signalR trigger function has been working well until we upgraded the NuGet packages to the latest versions.

```cs
[Function("OnConnected")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "myhub")]
public async Task<SignalRMessageAction> OnConnectedAsync([SignalRTrigger("myhub", "connections", "connected")] SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext)
{
    // do some stuff
    return new(target!)
    {
        ConnectionId = invocationContext.ConnectionId,
        Arguments = new object[] { "something" }
    };
}
```

The issue is that we started getting the following runtime exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.OnConnected'. Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> We inspected the NuGet package references and found that we are not referencing Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management in our packages list.

#### Repro steps

Create an upstream signalR function in a .NET 7.0 dotnet-isolated v4 function app and add the following NuGet packages:

```xml
    <PackageVersion Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageVersion Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageVersion Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageVersion Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.10.0" />
```

The dotnet version is 7.0.304

What is the workaround or fix for this roadblock?

Answer (score 0):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified

This error could be because of the upgradation of .NET version to 7.0.

To resolve this issue:

- Need to check if all the installed dependencies version compatible with the .NET version. It can be checked in [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options).
- Upgrade the package versions to its latest version which are compatible with the application's .NET version.
- Also check by Installing the below nuget packages through Nuget Package Manager:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management
```

[image]

**.csproj:**

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management" Version="1.21.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**References:**

Refer to similar [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/blob/main/samples/DotnetIsolated-ClassBased/DotnetIsolated-ClassBased.csproj) code given by Y-Sindo.

Comment: Unfortunately there’s an underlying issue with the budget pasckages per this GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2993

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed once Microsoft addresses [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1709).

At this moment, I had to downgrade the NuGet packages.